# formatting numerical values

Tags: r, formatting, printf

I would like to format numerical values, but during formatting they loose "numeric" quality. Is there a better option?

```
> values
[1]  5 10 20 30
> class(values[1])
[1] "numeric"
> class(values)
[1] "numeric"
> out<-sprintf("%6.2f",values)
> out
[1] "  5.00" " 10.00" " 20.00" " 30.00"
> class(out)
[1] "character"
> class(out[1])
[1] "character"
```

out is no longer numeric.

Comment: Can you add some context that describes exactly what you are doing with these values such that you desire them to be formatted in a particular way? It will make a difference in what the answer is.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `options` of `print` to change the number of digits printed :

```
R> print(3.141592, digits=3)
[1] 3.14
```

You can also set `options(digits)` to make it more or less permanent in your session :

```
R> options(digits=3)
R> print(3.141592)
[1] 3.14
```

But this will not necessarily apply to plots, etc.

Comment: Hi juba, but I would like to do formatting of values in data.frame, not just displaying on the screen. Thank you.